# WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x:8080/butlrr/chatroomServerEndPoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: websocket, tomcat7

I have a tomcat server running on amazon ec2 instance. When I used localhost to create a war file, it is working fine. But when I used public ip address it shows error - 
WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x:8080/butlrr/chatroomServerEndPoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200.

Instead I am able to check tomcat page on http://x.x.x.x:8080.

Please help me to out of this.

Comment: Please anyone help me. I am new to stackoverflow. Do i need to do something else.

Comment: You need to show what you did for others to help you out.

Comment: Finally resolved. Issue was, websocket-api.jar and tomcat7-websocket.jar are missing in lib directory of tomcat. I have added it and it works like a charm.